# Magento 2 - How to catch Exception when run batch file?

Tags: magento2, exception, messages

When I ran my batch file and get Excetion below:

[image]

I try to catch exception but I can not catch. My code sample is below:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    try {
        $sql = '';
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection();
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        ....
        }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->writeErrorLog($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But I can't not get message of Exception. So that, Anyone show me How to get message of Exception to write log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can execute Magento2 commands with the '-vvv' switch to get the debug output.

```
bin/magento batch:creteo -vvv
```

Also, if your class is in a namespace and you did not import the \Exception class (just assuming, can't see that in your example), it has to be \Exception in the catch block. Otherwise it will be searched for in your current namespace

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    try {
        $sql = '';
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection();
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        ....
        }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->writeErrorLog($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```